# How do I quickly position two windows side by side?

Tags: window-manager

Sometimes you need to see two windows side by side, e.g. when following instructions or when working on a translation. How do I quickly arrange two windows like that?

**edit:** interested in answers for all platforms and window managers

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: I'm assuming that you only have one monitor? :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are good solutions for both Mac and Windows that I know of:

### Windows 7

This feature is built in, and it's called **Aero Snap**.  You can use the following keyboard shortcuts to get the behavior you want:

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> moves the current window to the left half of the screen.
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> moves the current window to the right half of the screen.
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> maximes the current window.

### Windows XP and Vista

[GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) allows you to setup regions to snap windows to via a shortcut key. I mapped <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to move a window to the left half of the screen and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to use the right half.

[AeroSnap](http://www.aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm) makes Windows 7's native keyboard shortcuts available in Windows Vista and Windows XP.

### Mac OS X

[Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/), [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) (both unlimited free trials) and TwoUp (discontinued – available [here](http://download.cnet.com/TwoUp/3000-2346_4-10907668.html)) from Irradiated Software all accomplish this task perfectly. SizeUp adds some extra features, including multiple monitor support.

Comment: TwoUp has been discontinued and replaced by Cinch http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/index.html which seems to work very well

Comment: Just downloaded cinch and sizeup, both are nice

Answer (score 19):

Answer for Windows as [explained on the old new thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/07/28/9850416.aspx):

> In the taskbar, click the button for
>   the first window you want to position,
>   then hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and right-click
>   the button for the second window.
>   Select Tile Vertically. Bingo, the two
>   windows are positioned side by side.

As mentioned in a comment below, you can also hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you click an additional taskbar button and finally right-click a third one. In this way you can arrange 3  windows at the same time. More than 3 windows also works but results in a grid layout.

Comment: you can hold in Ctrl for all windows you want to arrange. So this will work for n windows

Comment: Also this is easier on Windows 7, where you can just drag the windows to either the left or the right side of the screen, where they dock.

Comment: Also, it does this per monitor, so that you can spread windows across screens, and tiling is done on a per-monitor basis

Comment: Note: this only works with two Windows I think else it will arrange all Windows like that, making a horrible mess...

Comment: Works with up to 3 windows on XP. Any more and they are tiled in a grid.

Comment: On Windows XP, any _maximised_ windows not selected appear to get _restored_ when the selected windows are tiled.

Answer (score 7):

## Mac OSX

Two excellent, free tools:

- [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) is ultra-simple and lets you setup shortcut keys to all the typical window placement actions (fill left half of screen, fill top half, full screen, center, etc).
- [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) is very full featured and can do these keyboard shortcuts as well, but also lets you click and drag windows to "snap" to different regions of the screen. (And it has tons of other features, since it's original purpose was custom touchpad gestures).

Answer (score 5):

For linux, get a tiling window manager (AwesomeWM, XMonad, dwm, ratpoison, musca..). If you don't like or are not familiar with automatic tiling, or you don't want to switch WMs, use some of the tiling scripts, like [stiler](http://github.com/TheWanderer/stiler/tree/master).

Answer (score 5):

In the newest Ubuntu versions that come preinstalled with Unity desktop manager and Compiz, the function is preinstalled. You can align the chosen window by doing the following:

- to fullscreen: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
- to left half: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- to right half: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

("Super" key is the name for the Windows key on Linux.)

You should be able to do this on other Linux distros too, as long as they are able to run [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org).

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LST it is possible to accomplish this task in additional way.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd>(keypad)

As a result it will place the window at:

- <kbd>1</kbd> -up left
- <kbd>2</kbd> -up center
- <kbd>3</kbd> -up right,
- <kbd>4</kbd> -middle left etc.
- <kbd>0</kbd> -minimize

Answer (score 1):

Try [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/). Basically it allows you to easily (via a few shortcuts) resize your window to exact proportions.